# Kafka-Ksql Rekeying on stream results in data disappearing after few min

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

The rekeying works fine in the following scenarios
1. Base topic to stream then rekey - Good
2. Table to stream then rekey - Good

But when trying with 
Table - Table join results in new table, create stream on that resulting table, then rekey stream - It appears to work fine for few minutes(select query gets the expected result), and then the data disappears from the newly created stream.

```
-- Table on Table join - works as expected
CREATE TABLE JOINRESULT_T AS 
SELECT d.DEVICE_ID, d.LOCATION_ALIAS,d.UPDATED_BY, 
d.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP AS UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, d.__DELETED AS __DELETED
FROM TABLE1 d LEFT JOIN TABLE2 l ON d.LOCATION_ALIAS=l.ALIAS;

-- Stream from table - works as expected
CREATE STREAM FROMJOIN_S WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='JOINRESULT_T', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

-- Rekey the above stream - Data disappears after few minutes
CREATE STREAM REKEY_S AS SELECT * FROM FROMJOIN_S PARTITION BY DEVICE_ID;
```

Describe extended command on the stream displays the count of messages the stream is currently holding. But a select command does not give out any results. 
The print topic command on the associated topic also does not print anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uvoD.png)

Ksql version : 5.3.1 , also tried latest version
Partitions = 1, replicas =1.

tried to investigate if the topic storage space on kafka server is holding any data and found the log file, snapshot files both to be empty.

what could cause the data to disappear once it is written to the topic?

Comment: Sorry, did you found a reason for such behavior? I also experience such a problem.

Comment: did not find the exact reason, but the issue was intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this is that the retention on the `REKEY_S` topic in the Kafka cluster is set low and so is aggressively deleting 'old' messages.

Try investigating that the retention policy / settings is for `REKEY_S` topic. The policy should NOT be compact, and should have the default topic retention policy set by the Kafka cluster.

If strange retention settings is the cause, then it would be good to know *why* the retention is being set that way and by *what*.  If the *what* is ksql, then its likely a bug and should be raised as a [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues) so it an be investigated.